# Python run certain functions with or without a client connection

Tags: python, networking, dependencies

I have a python program that handles sensor data. Most of the functionality takes place locally and requires no network connection. The one thing i want it to do with a client is send a continuous stream of data IF a client is connected but for everything else to run regardless of weather there is a connected client or not. The only setups I've managed before all required a client to connect before anything else could happen.

How do I set this up so my program doesn't depend on first having a client connected before it does anything??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to connect, and if it fails after n retries, consider you don't have a connection.

There are many strategies to setup retries, so search about it to figure what is best for you.

Then if you can't connect, just keep going on after the failure...

That's about it.

Comment: but this is the server not the client. I need it to listen for connections not look for them. my problem is that i cant get anything else to run unless there is a connection.

Comment: a server without internet connection is not a server. a server answers requests.

Comment: so what is your 'server' doing when it is not connected?

Comment: I guess you question is not clear: you are doing work when you receive a request (i.e. a client connects) but you want to run a 'job' every so often no matter if there are client connecting?

Comment: its more i want to run a job continuously whether there is a client or not and if there is a client then i want to do an additional job. sorry for not being clear.

Comment: what does running the job continuously involve? ou must have input and output, so what input is changing that you need to re-run the job? 
I'd look at worker threads like 
https://www.troyfawkes.com/learn-python-multithreading-queues-basics/
to run background jobs.

Comment: I'm reading data from a temperature sensor, receiving input from a keypad and controlling a solid state relay based on those inputs.

Comment: so, i think you need to separate concerns here, and have your process run, looking for the inputs your read (keypad, sensors etc...) and do whatever it needs to do. Then have a server receive requests, and the server can look up the data to do something with the request data and the process data.
The process data could be in a file locally, or a database (like SQLLite) so the server can look it up easily.

Comment: so 2 separate programs running at the same time?